# pass variable to strtotime in php

Tags: php

My question is that when I get the time duration for example 15 min. duration per hour in database and these value store in variable and then these variables are passed to the  strtotime("+15 minutes") then they get error.  How do I solve this problem?

My code is here:

```
$custom = $book_u['custom_min'] = $row['custom_min'];
$start_time=explode(',',$row['start_time']);
while($t==0)
{
    $t=1;
    $endTime2 = strtotime("+1".$custom."minutes", strtotime($endTime));
    $starts_t[]=date('h:i a', strtotime($endTime));
    $ends_t[]=date('h:i a', $endTime2);
    //echo  date('h:i a', strtotime($endTime)).'-'.date('h:i a', $endTime2).'</br>';
    $endTime=date('h:i a', strtotime("+15 mins", $endTime2));
    if(strtotime($endTime)>strtotime($finalTime)){
        $t=1;
    }
else $t=0;
}
```

Comment: whats the error your getting

Answer (score 0):

The `strtotime()` function will generate a timestamp which equates to the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC, relative to the timestamp.

So your input into the function must always be a value that contains at least a date.  Using just a time value will cause you problems.

Here is an example of how to use the function:

```
$endTime = '2018-08-10 22:00:00';  //End time must be a date reference.
//Using just a time like 22:00:00 will cause you problems.

$custom = '15'; //Number of minutes
$end_t = date('h:i a', strtotime($endTime . ' +' . $custom . ' minutes'));
//Notice where the spaces are. The strtotime() part will read "2018-08-10 22:00:00 +15 minutes"

echo $end_t; //outputs "10:15 pm"
```

Comment: facing this error
This page isn’t working
dogselan.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
not working this code brother any other solution

Comment: i am trying this code but its not working any one can help me?

$startTime = "01:00 PM"; $finalTime="04:25 PM";
$custom = 20;
$endTime=$startTime;
$t=0;
while($t==0)
{
$t=1;
  $endTime2 = date('+' . $custom . ' minutes', strtotime($endTime));
  //$endTime2 = date('h:i a', strtotime($endTime . ' +' . $custom . ' minutes'));
$array[] = date('h:i a', strtotime($endTime)).'-'.date('h:i a', $endTime2).'</br>';
 $endTime=date('h:i a', $endTime2);
if(strtotime($endTime)>strtotime($finalTime)){
$t=1;
}
else $t=0;
}
$test = $array;
print_r($test);